# A function that takes in a string of numbers and returns the integer without the use of the built-in int() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a function that takes in a string e.g. '142' and return it as an integer, without the use of the int() function. I'm not sure where to start at all and the 'hint' provided to us is to use a list such as

```
digits = list('0123456789')
```

edit: We have not yet learnt chr, ord, eval() or ast.literal_eval? We have not yet learnt what string and integer literals are nor have we learnt dictionaries. for loops as well as 'in' are discouraged as well.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to approach this?

Comment: hint: play with `chr` and `ord` (specifically `ord`)

Comment: you can use `eval()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert "String" to "Int" without using library functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406072/how-to-convert-string-to-int-without-using-library-functions-in-python)

Comment: Think about what positional number representation *means*. The digit sequence `142` means 1*100 + 4*10 + 2*1. Figure out how to get Python to compute that.

Comment: If ``int`` is not allowed, *what else is not allowed either*? Can you use ``chr``, ``ord`` and similar? What about ``float`` or ``ast.literal_eval``? Are string and integer literals allowed? What about dicts? Please [edit] your question to make the constraints clear – it will be reopened when it is a clearly defined, distinct question.

Comment: Second level of hint: just implement in Python what human do when reading a decimal number: value of last digit + value of prev. digit * 10... Last point: in any system I know the value of a digit is the code of that digit minus the code of 0 (`ord(digit) - ord('0')` in Python).

Answer (score 0):

From `'5768'` you can get `8 * 1 + 6 * 10 + 7 * 100 + 5 * 1000`. You can use a loop to access the characters of the string and you have to keep track of the multiplier.

`index` can be used to find the position of the current character in the list and then you have the correct integer value for multiplication.

```
digits = list('0123456789')
value = 0
exp = 0
for c in reversed('5768'):
    print(f'c={c} exp={exp}')
    i = digits.index(c)
    value += i * 10 ** exp
    exp += 1
print(value)
```

---

After getting some more constraints in the question this code can be adjusted to the following.

```
digits = list('0123456789')
number = '5768'
value = 0
character_position = 0
while character_position < len(number):
    i = digits.index(number[character_position])
    value += i * 10 ** (len(number) - character_position - 1)
    character_position += 1
print(value)
```

---

A one liner solution:

```
print(sum('0123456789'.index(c) * 10 ** exp for exp, c in enumerate(reversed('5768'))))
```

Comment: Since code like this will never be used in production and the hint was to use the list `list('0123456789')` I decided to use `index`.

Answer (score -1):

Convert to int using eval:

```
str = '0123456789'


def str_to_int(str):
    return eval(str.lstrip("0"))


print(str_to_int(str))
print(type(str_to_int(str)))
```

Returns:

```
123456789
<class 'int'>
```